# Can't find Powershell command to grant admin consent

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2b

I have one Azure Ad app created via powershell.

I added permissions using Add-AzADAppPermission by following this document: [Add-AzADAppPermission (Az.Resources) | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/add-azadapppermission?view=azps-8.1.0)
Now I want to grant admin consent for the added permissions via powershell but I can't find any related command or any ms doc.

Is there any command that I can use to grant admin consent from powershell?

Can anyone please shed light on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***AFAIK, currently PowerShell don't have any command for granting admin consent.***

**Alternatively**, you can make use of Azure CLI/Azure Portal to achieve your scenario as suggested by **Joy Wang** in this similar [***SO Thread***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529599/how-to-grant-admin-consent-to-an-azure-aad-app-in-powershell#:%7E:text=There%20is%20no%20command%20to,consent%20button%20in%20the%20portal.).

*I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:*

I assigned the **API permissions** that need admin consent:

[image]

To grant the **admin consent**, execute the below command:

```
az login
az ad app permission admin-consent --id <application-id>
```

[image]

**After executing the above command, admin consent for the API permissions granted successfully like below:**

[image]

**Reference:**

[az ad app permission | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/ad/app/permission?view=azure-cli-latest#az-ad-app-permission-admin-consent)